# Any Application to bind various documents

Tags: microsoft-office, documents

I communicate with the client using various tools such as MS Outlook,Mailing through Google/ Yahoo accounts, sending Word or Excel documents as attachments through this mail. What I am looking at is there any tool which will help me in binding all these documents so that I may be able to virtually bind all these documents of a particular client.

For example all these documents were sent to Client A

2 Outlook mails without attachment
2 Web mails with MS-Word attachment
1 Web Mail with Excel attachment

Now I wish I had a document which would bind
the Outlook mail bodies as text files
MS-Word documents
Excel document

Previous versions of MS-Office had Office Binder. Is there something similar to this

Thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alternative to Microsoft Office Binder these days *(from Microsoft)* is [Microsoft Office OneNote](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/onenote/default.aspx).